# Facebook Open Graph image property

Tags: magento2, meta-tags

Facebook is picking up the wrong image from my Magento web site when shared. I have added the following line to my head.phtml

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.sturdykids.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/megashop-blue/images/logo.gif" />
```

It is definately in the right place when I view source of web site but the facebook debugger is still saying there is no og:image property.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook shows old scrapped page on share. You can update your page on it's debugger tool.

Search your page on : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

It will show old version of your website, then press **"Scrap Again"** button, it will update your scrapped page and it will show new image

Comment: I think you fixed the issue of unsupported image, I have checked on debug tool, It is showing image in preview: https://www.screencast.com/t/fGG2Kvonj

Comment: I've resolved it with og:image:secure_url instead. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's good. You are welcome :)

Comment: Please mark answer correct, so that it would be helpful for others in future :)